Identify classes that could be replaced by one generic class?
Imagine a larger codebase. Is there any tool or functionality built-in in Rider or Visual Studio that can recognize classes that are similar except for maybe just different data types? So a functionality that could give a hint like "hey those 3 classes, you could replace them by a generic one".

The concept of similarity is not impossible but also not that easy to automate. I don't know of any such tool or analyzer (which doesn't mean much). Not sure if anyone could have enough instances of this in one code base to feel the need for having this automated and then writing said automation.

Visual Studio itself does not provide such tool. If needed, you can submit a feature request on Developer community.

I'm not sure if it was your question. I'm suggesting two approaches:

Interfaces
Generic classes

Interfaces
public interface IVehicle {
  float Speed {get;}
  void Move(float acceleration);
}

All your classes that enherits from an interface must the interface's methods and properties.
public class Car : IVehicle {
  private float _speed;
  float Speed {
    get => _speed;
  }
  void Move(float acceleration) {
    speed += acceleration * time;
  }
}

Generic classes
public class List<T> { }

Allows you to use any class instead of 'T'.
Miceosoft Documentation Generic Classes
